# Meteor Aldeed:tabular - unable to render buttons extensions

Tags: javascript, meteor, datatables, aldeed-tabular

I have followed the instructions as mentioned in the Read Me regarding use of extensions with the tabular table [link](https://github.com/longshotlabs/meteor-tabular#integrating-datatables-extensions). However, doing so does not get me the extra set of buttons on my table. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong. If someone could guide me with this issue, it would be most helpful!

**index.js**

```
import dataTablesBootstrap from "datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js";
import "datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css";
dataTablesBootstrap(window, $);

// BUTTONS DATATABLES

import dataTableButtons from "datatables.net-buttons-bs4";
// Import whichever buttons you are using
import columnVisibilityButton from "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js";
import html5ExportButtons from "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js";
import flashExportButtons from "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js";
import printButton from "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js";

// Then initialize everything you imported
dataTableButtons(window, $);
columnVisibilityButton(window, $);
html5ExportButtons(window, $);
flashExportButtons(window, $);
printButton(window, $);
```

**table.js**

```
import Tabular from "meteor/aldeed:tabular";
// import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

new Tabular.Table({
    name: "listUsersTable",
    collection: Meteor.users,
    autoWidth: false,
    order: [
        [0, "asc"],
        // [1, "desc"],
    ],

    // results dropdown
    lengthMenu: [
        [10, 25, 50, 100], // value
        [10, 25, 50, 100], // label
    ],
    // other properties...
    buttonContainer: ".col-sm-6:eq(0)",
    buttons: ["copy", "excel", "csv", "colvis"],
    throttleRefresh: 5000, // throttle the reactivity
    search: {
        caseInsensitive: true,
        smart: true,
        onEnterOnly: true,
    },
    responsive: true,
   
    columns: [
        {
            data: "username",
            title: "Username",
            width: "20%",
            autoWidth: false,
        },

        {
            title: "Profile",
            bSortable: false,
            width: "40%",
            tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.edit_user_links,
            tmplContext(rowData) {
                return {
                    item: rowData,
                    column: "profile",
                };
            },
        },
// other columns 
]
});
```

I am unable to view the "copy", "excel", "csv", "colvis" buttons anywhere around my table. In addition to this, I would like to know the role of `"buttonContainer: ".col-sm-6:eq(0)",` Am I supposed to declare a div with that class?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with Meteor/Aldeed - but when using native DataTables, you need to use the [`dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) in your table definition to get your buttons to be displayed. More specifically you have to include `B` for "buttons" - for example: `"dom": "Blfrtip"`.

Comment: Have you found anything about this yet?

Comment: @user2402616 - Nothing as of yet, I will try a couple of things in a few days. Just focusing on something else right now.

Comment: Sounds good! I went through the `datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js` src and found nothing glaring yet. THat might be a place to start though. It's not too large a file